# Access 2016 using requery or refresh on events

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have an access database where the combo drop down box is a link table in SQL.  Whenever i update the drop down value in SQL i have to close the form and re-open to see the changes. Question? Can i use Combo1.Requery or me.refresh in event Got Focus and Lost Focus?